# Assignment with function or method

Tags: python, scheme, variable-assignment, interpreter, assignment-operator

Is there any way to assign a value to a variable, in python, with a function or method? I am writing a Scheme interpreter and the process would be greatly simplified if I could. This can be done for basic logic and math with the operator module like so:

```
>>> operator.add(2, 3)
5
```

Example of what I mean

```
>>> operator.assign(a, 5)
>>> print(a)
5
```

Comment: Basic variable assignment works like `x = operator.add(2, 3)`, but I assume that is not what you meant. Can you provide an example of a line of code with the expected output?

Comment: That `assign` can't be implemented since Python doesn't support call-by-reference. It's not obvious how this would simplify anything, though. Do you have an example?

Comment: Basically I have a bunch of symbols linked to functions in a dictionary. If the program reads a `+` then it looks for it in the dictionary and feeds it two arguments. I would like to do the same thing for `define` for variable definitions.

Comment: @ayNONE Use the same mechanism – mapping names to values in a dictionary. Don't involve Python variables in it.

Answer (score 1):

The need for this functionality may be a hint that the program design needs rethinking.

You did not provide any details, but a separate namespace might be required to prevent name clashes.

For example, all variables assignable this way could be stored in a container of some kind maybe even in a separate module. No "tricks" would be required.

After these warnings, here is an example. It can (re)assing any name in the current module.

```
import sys

this_module = sys.modules[__name__]

def assign(name, value):
    setattr(this_module, name, value)

a = 1000
assign('b', a + 3)
print(b)  # 1003
```

Answer (score 1):

You really really don't want to mash together the python namespace and the scheme namespace. The python variables are part of the implementation of the interpreter, and the scheme variables are part of the evaluated program. Your job is to represent the environment of the evaluated program using values in the host language. A dictionary would probably be a fine choice. But do you really want a scheme program that defines a variable called 'main' to stomp your implementation's definition of main? I think not.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Sample:

    res = None

    def Add(self, x, y):
        self.res = x + y

obj = Sample()
obj.Add(2, 3)
print obj.res
```

You can use class variables, here operation is performed and result is stored in class variable **res**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you'll provide a variable name to assign the value to. This'll involve modifying the value in the caller scope - this is not recommended but here's a way to do so:

**Sample code:**

```
import inspect
def assign(var_name, value):
    inspect.stack()[1][0].f_locals[var_name] = value

try:
  print("a={}".format(a))
except Exception as err:
  print("ERROR: {}".format(err))

assign('a', 10)

try:
  print("a={}".format(a))
except Exception as err:
  print("ERROR: {}".format(err))
```

**Execution output:**

```
ERROR: name 'a' is not defined
a=10
```

Comment: Oh my. I would bet large amounts of money that this is not the best solution to OP's problem.

Comment: @JohnClements I wouldn't bet :) Because I agree with you. It's one of the simplest ones though.